# Тест при переносе строк "уходит" под картинку [div + css]

Tags: css

Не могу понять в чем дело.

Есть код:

```
<style type="text/css">
.relatimg { 
width:100px;
height:100px;
   }
.block{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
  </style>
<div class="block"><a href="stoimost.htm"><img src="potol.jpg"
class="relatimg" alt="надпись" title="Натяжные потолки в ванной" align="middle"></a></div>
<div class="block"><p><a href="stoimost.htm" rel="bookmark" title="Надпись">
Надпись на которую нужно нажать</a></p> </div>
```

Выводит этот код примерно следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, если текст в строке длинный, то он почему то уходит под картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне соответственно нужно чтобы текст, вне зависимости от длины был справа по центру от картинки. Подскажите советом как поправить?

Answer (score 0):

сделайте общий контейнер для 2 дивов и задайте ему стиль

```
"display: flex; flex-direction: row;"
```

остальные свойства (align-items, justify-content) подберите в зависимости от того, какой вид вам нужен.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Получилось! :)

Comment: @ДенИнвест, отметьте ответ как правильный. если кто-то зайдет сюда с этим же вопросом, то он сразу поймет, как решить эту проблему.